# Backbone one-off ajax request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple List-style Backbone app that I'm making with a Rails backend.

I have a collection:

```
var ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Item,

  initialize: function(id) {
    this.id = id;
  },

  url: function(){
    return '/lists/' + this.id + '/items';
  },

});
```

All the standard CRUD operations work fine from the model. But I have an "extra" route - "clear" that will clear all the items in a list at one show. The route would be:

```
/lists/[:id]/clear
```

Because this is outside the normal CRUD operations, is there way to hook it into the normal Collection, or do i do something separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a method on your collection called `destroy` and inside there you can take one of several approaches to making the AJAX request (in order of harmony with Backbone). Note you probably don't want to call your collection method `clear` because Backbone Models already have a `clear` method with different semantics.

1. create a throw-away `Backbone.Model` instance with the correct URL and ID and then call 'destroy' on it
2. Call Backbone.sync with method "delete" and a throw-away model object with just an 'url' property and empty 'toJSON' function with the right ID
3. Make a direct jQuery `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 2):

You could add your own method that executes `/lists/:id/clear` and then does a [`reset`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset) on the collection when it is done:

```
clear: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/lists/' + this.id + '/clear',
        //...
        success: function() {
            _this.reset();
        }
    });
}
```

When you call `reset` without any arguments, it removes all the models from the collection.

Comment: My only caveat here is that this could be confusing because Backbone Models have a method called `clear` that clears in-browser data without contacting the server. Could be confusing. Probably better to use `destroy`.